# Magento 1.9 - How to solve GoDaddy Hosting Timeout Error?

Tags: server, magento-1.9, vps, connection-timeout, orocrm

I have VPS server in GoDaddy, configuration 8 GB Ram and 4 Core CPU Process.

Frequently i am getting following error,

[image]

Note :  I am using OroCRM, in my Apache status Request -> **index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl=1** so many url sending reply. How to set resource limit.